# Scroll Bar Listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to create a pop-up window that contains a listbox with a scrollbar. However, I do not understand why nothing displays when I run the code in Python. As always, thank you very much!

```
from Tkinter import *

def run():
    # create the root and the canvas
    root = Tk()
    canvasW, canvasH = 300, 200
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvasW, height=canvasH)
    canvas.pack()
    class Struct: pass
    canvas.data = Struct()
    init(canvas)
    root.mainloop()  

def init(canvas):
    master = Tk()
    # use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
    master.geometry("240x180+130+180")
    # create the listbox (height/width in char)
    listbox = Listbox(master, width=20, height=6)
    listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
    yscroll = Scrollbar(command=listbox.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    # now load the listbox with data
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
    for item in numbers:
        # insert each new item to the end of the listbox
        listbox.insert(END, item)
run()
```

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan Oakley said earlier, part of the problem is the multiple instances of the `Tk` class. I think the `Canvas` object is unnecessary as well. Here is a simple case which works:

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master

        self.yscroll = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.yscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.list = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
        for item in xrange(100):
            self.list.insert(END, item)
        self.list.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.yscroll.config(command=self.list.yview)

def run():
    root = Tk()

    app = MyList(root)
    root.mainloop()

run()
```

I found [this site](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) and [this site](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/all_programs.html) very useful when I had to make something with Tkinter. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem (or part of the problem) is that you are creating two instances of the `Tk` class. A tkinter program needs exactly one instance of `Tk`.